# How to save updated an embedded picklist selection on a custom Lightning Datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am using a 'Custom Datatable' solution in order to modify picklist values within a datatable. Project code may be referenced here:
https://live.playg.app/play/picklist-in-lightning-datatable

I have made changes so that I can retrieve data from the custom object: Payment__c, and I am attempting modify the picklist values for the Payment_Status__c field. My 'debugging' method has been to create numerous console.log statements to verify data during the updating process. Picklist values are currently hardcoded (have not figured out how to dynamically pull from SF yet). Inline edit of individual cells works fine, and I am able to save those values as well (though changes are not reflected until I perform a manual page refresh). Picklist selection is working, but I am unable to save the currently selected picklist value in the datatable.

I believe that the intended trigger event for picklist selection changes--'valueselect', is not being fired, and the handleSelection method is not receiving this event when a new picklist selection is made.

The lightning component used on Salesforce is c-customDatatableDemo:

```
customDatatableDemo.js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getPayments from '@salesforce/apex/PaymentController.getPayments';
import saveRecords from '@salesforce/apex/PaymentController.saveRecords';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class CustomDatatableDemo extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    //have this attribute to track data changed
    //with custom picklist or custom lookup  
    @track draftValues = [];

    @track lastSavedData = [];

    connectedCallback() { 
        this.columns = [
            {
            label: 'Name',
            fieldName: 'Name',
            editable: false
        }, {
            label: 'Invoice Number',
            fieldName: 'Invoice_Number__c',
            editable: true
        }, {
            label: 'Invoice Amount',
            fieldName: 'Invoice_Amount__c',
            type: 'currency',
            editable: true
        }, {
            label: 'Invoice Date',
            fieldName: 'Invoice_Date__c',
            type: 'date',
            editable: true
        }, {
            label: 'Payment Status',
            fieldName: 'Payment_Status__c',
            type: 'picklist',
            typeAttributes:
            {
                placeholder: 'Choose Status',
                options: [
                    { label: 'Needs to Be Paid', value: 'Needs to Be Paid' },
                    { label: 'Issued', value: 'Issued' },
                    { label: 'Voided', value: 'Voided' },
                ] // List of Payment Status picklist options
                , value: {fieldName: 'Payment_Status__c' } // default value for picklist
                , context: {fieldName: 'Id' } // binding Payment Id with context variable to be returned back
            }
            },
            {
                label: 'Description', fieldName: 'Work_Description__c', type: 'text', editable: true
            }];
    
        //  Get Payments data
        getPayments()
        .then(result => {
            this.data = result;
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        })

        // Save last saved copy
        this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    }   

    updateDataValues(updateItem) {
        console.log('START--updateDataValues()');
        let copyData = [... this.data];
        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    console.log('updateDataValues() item.Id = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem.Id));
                    console.log('updateItem[field] = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem[field]));
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                    console.log('UPDATED--item[field] = ' + updateItem[field]);
                }
            }
        });

        //write changes back to original data
        this.data = [...copyData];
        console.log('this.data = ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
        let tempData = [...this.data];
        //console.log('tempData = ' + JSON.stringify(tempData));
        console.log('END--updateDataValues()');
    }

    updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
        console.log('START--updateDraftValues()');
        console.log('stringify draft updateItem = ' + JSON.stringify(updateItem));
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = [...this.draftValues];
        //store changed value to do operations
        //on save. This will enable inline editing &
        //show standard cancel & save button
        let i = 0;
        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                i++;
                console.log('i = ' + i);
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    console.log(i + '. UpdateDraftValues--item id if selected...item Id = ' + item.Id + ' & item value = ' + item.value);
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                    console.log('item[field] = ' + updateItem[field]);
                }
                draftValueChanged = true;
                console.log('draftValueChanged = TRUE');
            }
        });

        //draftValueChanged = true;

        if (draftValueChanged) {
            console.log('YESdraftValueChanged');
            console.log('copyDraftValues = ' + JSON.stringify(copyDraftValues));
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
            //console.log('draftValues = ' + JSON.stringify(draftValues));
        } else {
            console.log('NOdraftValue!Changed');
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
            let testDraftValues = {... this.draftValues};
            console.log('JSON.stringify(testDraftValues) = ' + JSON.stringify(testDraftValues));
        }
        console.log('STOP--updateDraftValues()')
    }

    //listener handler to get the context and data
    //updates datatable
    picklistChanged(event) {
        console.log('START--picklistChanged()');
        console.log('EVENT type - ' + event.type);
        event.stopPropagation();
        let dataReceived = event.detail.data;
        
        let updatedItem = { ...dataReceived };
        console.log('picklistChanged()...updatedItem = ' + JSON.stringify(updatedItem));
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);
        /* console.log('event.value = ' + event.value);
        this.value = event.target.value;
        event.stopPropagation();
        let dataReceived = event.detail.data;
        let updatedItem = { ...dataReceived };
        console.log('updatedItem.context ' + updatedItem.context);
        console.log('updatedItem.value ' + updatedItem.value);
        console.log('updatedItem = ' + JSON.stringify(updatedItem));
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);
        console.log('picklistChanged() = ' + JSON.stringify(updatedItem)); */
        console.log('STOP--picklistChanged()');
    }

    handleSelection(event) {
        console.log('START--handleSelection()');
        this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
        console.log('this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);')
        /* event.stopPropogation();
        let dataReceived = event.detail.data;
        let updatedItem = { ...dataReceived };
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem); */
        console.log('STOP--handleSelection() = ' + JSON.stringify(updatedItem));
    }

    //handler to handle cell changes & update values in draft values
    handleCellChange(event) {
        console.log('START--handleCellChange()');
        console.log('handleCellChange');
        this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
        console.log('handleCellChange value = ' + JSON.stringify(this.updateDraftValues));
        console.log('END--handleCellChange()');
    }

    handleSave(event) {
        if (event.type === 'picklistchanged'){

        }
        console.log('START--handleSave');
        console.log('Updated items = ', this.draftValues);
        // save last saved copy
        this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        console.log('this.lastSavedData = ' + JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));

        this.fldsItemValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        console.log('this.fldsItemValues = ' + JSON.stringify(this.fldsItemValues));

        const inputsItems = this.fldsItemValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            console.log('JSON.stringify() fields ' + JSON.stringify(fields));
            return { fields };
        });

       // Show toast after successful update
        const promises = inputsItems.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Records Updated Successfully!!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            this.fldsItemValues = [];
            return this.refresh();
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'An Error Occured!!',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }).finally(() => {
            // Clear draft values
            this.draftValues = [];
        });

        
        // Refresh the window after successful save
        //window.open('url','_self');
        //document.location.reload(true);
        
        //cmp.find("table-component-id").set("v.draftValues", null);
        console.log('END--handleSave');
    }

    handleCancel(event) {
        //remove draftValues & revert data changes
        this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));
        this.draftValues = [];
    }

    async refresh() {
        console.log('async refresh');
        await refreshApex(this.data);
        //this.connectedCallback();
    }
}



customDatatableDemo.html

<template>
    <lightning-card title="Invoicing" icon-name="custom:custom17">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={data}>
                <c-custom-data-table
                object-api-name="Payment__c"
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={data}
                    value=""
                    show-row-number-column
                    columns={columns}
                    onpicklistchanged={picklistChanged}
                    onvalueselect={handleSelection}
                    draft-values={draftValues}
                    oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                    onsave={handleSave}
                    oncancel={handleCancel}>
                </c-custom-data-table>
                <template if:true={data.error}></template>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    <p>Selected value is: {value}</p>
</template>



customDataTable.js

import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
//import the template so that it can be reused
import DatatablePicklistTemplate from './picklist-template.html';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import CustomDataTableResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/CustomDataTable';

export default class CustomDataTable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        picklist: {
            template: DatatablePicklistTemplate,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context'],
        },
    
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, CustomDataTableResource),
        ]).then(() => {})
    }
}




picklist-template.html (Same folder as customDataTable)
<template>
    <c-datatable-picklist label={typeAttributes.label} value={typeAttributes.value}
        placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder} options={typeAttributes.options} context={typeAttributes.context}>
    </c-datatable-picklist>
</template>



datatablePicklist.js
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class DatatablePicklist extends LightningElement {
    @api label;
    @api placeholder;
    @api options;
    @api value;
    @api context;

    handleChange(event) {
        //show the selected value on UI
        this.value = event.detail.value;

        //fire event to send context and selected value to the data table
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('picklistchanged', {
            composed: true,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            detail: {
                data: { context: this.context, value: this.value }
            }
        }));
    }
}



datatablePicklist.html
<template>
    <div class="picklist-container">
        <lightning-combobox name="picklist" label={label} value={value} placeholder={placeholder} options={options}
        onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>}
    </div>
</template>



lwcEditSaveRow.js

import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/lwcEditSaveRowCtrl.getAccounts';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
    }, {
        label: 'Phone',
        fieldName: 'Phone',
        type: 'phone',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        label: 'Industry',
        fieldName: 'Industry',
        type: 'text',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        label: 'Type',
        fieldName: 'Type',
        type: 'text',
        editable: true
    }, {
        label: 'Description',
        fieldName: 'Type',
        type: 'text',
        editable: true
    }
    
];
export default class LwcEditSaveRow extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    @track accObj;
    fldsItemValues = [];

    @wire(getAccounts)
    cons(result) {
        this.accObj = result;
        if (result.error) {
            this.accObj = undefined;
        }
    };

    saveHandleAction(event) {
        this.fldsItemValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        const inputsItems = this.fldsItemValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return { fields };
        });

       
        const promises = inputsItems.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Records Updated Successfully!!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            this.fldsItemValues = [];
            return this.refresh();
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'An Error Occured!!',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }).finally(() => {
            this.fldsItemValues = [];
        });
    }

   
    async refresh() {
        await refreshApex(this.accObj);
    }
}

lwcEditSaveRow.html

<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <h3 class="slds-text-heading_medium"><lightning-icon icon-name="custom:custom84" size="small"></lightning-icon> <strong style="color:#270086; font-size:13px; margin-right:5px;"> How to inline Edit/Save Rows With Lightning Datatable in Lightning Web Component (LWC) </strong></h3>
        <br/><br/>
        <template if:true={accObj.data}>
            <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" 
            data={accObj.data} 
            columns={columns} 
            onsave={saveHandleAction}
            draft-values={fldsItemValues} 
            hide-checkbox-column 
            show-row-number-column>
           </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
        <br/>
         <br/>
   <!--Start RelatedTopics Section-->
<div style="border:1px #ddd solid; padding:10px; background:#eee; margin:40px 0;">
            
            <p data-aura-rendered-by="435:0"><img src="https://www.w3web.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/thumbsUpLike.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:top; margin-right:10px;" data-aura-rendered-by="436:0"><strong data-aura-rendered-by="437:0"><span style="font-size:16px; font-style:italic; display:inline-block; margin-right:5px;">Don't forget to check out:-</span><a href="https://www.w3web.net/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-decoration:none;" data-aura-rendered-by="440:0">An easy way to learn step-by-step online free Salesforce tutorial, To know more Click  <span style="color:#ff8000; font-size:18px;" data-aura-rendered-by="442:0">Here..</span></a></strong></p>
 
            <br/><br/>
            <p data-aura-rendered-by="435:0"><img src="https://www.w3web.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/tickMarkIcon.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:top; margin-right:10px;" data-aura-rendered-by="436:0"><strong data-aura-rendered-by="437:0"><span style="font-size:17px; font-style:italic; display:inline-block; margin-right:5px; color:rgb(255 128 0);">You May Also Like →</span> </strong></p>
            <div style="display:block; overflow:hidden;"> 
                <div style="width: 50%; float:left; display:inline-block">
                    <ul style="list-style-type: square; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 0 54px; padding: 0;"> 
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/lwc-get-set-lightning-checkbox-value/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">How to get selected checkbox value in lwc</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/display-account-related-contacts-in-lwc/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">how to display account related contacts based on AccountId in lwc</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/create-lightning-datatable-row-actions-in-lwc/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">how to create lightning datatable row actions in lwc</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/if-and-else-condition-in-lwc/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">how to use if and else condition in lwc</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/get-selected-radio-button-value-and-checked-default-in-lwc/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">how to display selected radio button value in lwc</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
 
            <div style="width: 50%; float:left; display:inline-block">
                    <ul style="list-style-type: square; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 0 54px; padding: 0;"> 
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/display-account-related-contacts-lwc/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">display account related contacts based on account name in lwc</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/create-lightning-datatable-row-actions-in-lwc/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">how to insert a record of account Using apex class in LWC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/fetch-picklist-values-dynamic-in-lwc/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">how to get picklist values dynamically in lwc</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/edit-save-and-remove-rows-dynamically-in-lightning-component/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">how to edit/save row dynamically in lightning component</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.w3web.net/update-parent-object-from-child/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">update parent field from child using apex trigger</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
               <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
               <br/>
                <div class="youtubeIcon">
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW62gTen2zniILj9xE6LmOg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://www.w3web.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/youtubeIcon.png" width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align:top; margin-right:10px;"/> <strong>TechW3web:-</strong> To know more, Use this <span style="color: #ff8000; font-weight: bold;">Link</span> </a>
                </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
 
  <!--End RelatedTopics Section-->
    </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Example of changing and saving non-picklist value in datatable:
[Changing and saving non-picklist value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rtsG.jpg)

Example of changing and saving a picklist value:
[Changing and saving picklist value (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL5i9.jpg)

Last bit of console output:
[Changing and saving picklsit value (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcjkh.jpg)

As this is my first time working with Lightning Web components, I would greatly appreciate any assistance you may provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this custom data table component working for something I am developing to effectively bind records as rows. Here 2 differences I notice:

- I did not include onvalueselect and oncellchange methods for the component html declaration, only the onpicklistchanged.
- You may want to use your custom server side controller method instead of the built-in uiRecordApi->updateRecord one. Something tells me this may not play nice with row data from the data table. In my implementation, I was simply able to pass the draftValues over to the server side method which has a  single parameter of list of sObject:

  ```
  async saveRecords(event){
       const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;
       this.draftValues = [];
       this.showSpinner = true
       try{
           await saveRelatedRecords({sObjs: updatedFields}) // server side save
               .then((result) => {
                   this.updateMessage = result;
               })

           this.showSpinner = false;
           if(this.updateMessage == 'success'){
               this.showToast('Success', 'Record(s) Updated', 'success');
           } else{
               this.showToast('Error', this.updateMessage, 'error');
           }
           await refreshApex(this._wiredRecordData);
           this.unsavedData = this.records;
       } catch (error) {
           this.showSpinner = false;
           this.showToast('Error while updating or refreshing records', error.body.message, 'error');
       }
   }
  ```

In regards to your data not refreshing, I suggest you wire your getPayments method so that you can always get a fresh set from the server side, rather than trying to keep track of and maintain data changes on the client side, something like:

```
_wiredRecordData;
@wire(getRelatedRecords)
relatedRecords(getRecsResult){
    const { data, error } = getRecsResult;
    this._wiredRecordData = getRecsResult;
    if(data){
        this.records = data;
    }
}
```

Then after your success toast in your save method, you can use
`await refreshApex(_wiredRecords);` and lwc knows to rerender based on the wiring (or at least I think that's how it works.)

Lastly, here is the server side controller method I have to dynamically generate column header information so it does not need to be hard coded into the component. However I did need to modify the custom component a bit to include a new "fieldapi" attribute so that the client side method knows what field to set for the changed value during the onpicklistchanged action.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getColumnHeaders(String sObjAPI, String fieldAPIs)
{
    List<ColumnHeaderInfo> colHeaders = new List<ColumnHeaderInfo>();
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjDesc = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjAPI).getDescribe();
    Boolean objIsUpdateable = sObjDesc.isUpdateable();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objFields =  sObjDesc.fields.getMap();
    for(String field: fieldAPIs.split(','))
    {
        if(!objFields.keySet().contains(field.toLowerCase())){
            continue;
        }
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDesc = objFields.get(field).getDescribe();
        if(!fieldDesc.isAccessible()){
            continue;
        }
        ColumnHeaderInfo colHeader = new ColumnHeaderInfo();
        colHeader.label = fieldDesc.getLabel();
        colHeader.fieldName = fieldDesc.getName();
        colHeader.editable = fieldDesc.isUpdateable() && sObjDesc.isUpdateable();
        colHeader.type_x  = fieldDesc.getType().name().toLowerCase();
        
        if(colHeader.type_x == 'picklist')
        {
            colHeader.type_x = 'picklist';
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = fieldDesc.getPicklistValues();
            colHeader.typeAttributes = new TypeAttributes();
            colHeader.typeAttributes.options = new List<Option>();
            for(Schema.PicklistEntry ple: picklistValues)
            {
                Option opt = new Option();
                opt.value = ple.getValue();
                opt.label = ple.getLabel();
                colHeader.typeAttributes.options.add(opt);
            }
            colHeader.typeAttributes.context = new FieldName();
            colHeader.typeAttributes.context.fieldName = 'Id';
            colHeader.typeAttributes.value = new FieldName();
            colHeader.typeAttributes.value.fieldName = fieldDesc.getName();
            colHeader.typeAttributes.fieldapi = fieldDesc.getName();
        }
        // multi-select picklist fields not supported so make them read-only
        if(colHeader.type_x == 'multipicklist'){
            colHeader.editable = false;
        }
        colHeaders.add(colHeader);
    }

    return JSON.serialize(colHeaders).replaceAll('type_x', 'type');
}

private class ColumnHeaderInfo
{
    public String label;
    public String fieldName;
    public String type_x;
    public Boolean editable;
    public TypeAttributes typeAttributes;
}

private class TypeAttributes
{
    public String placeholder;
    public List<Option> options;
    public FieldName value;
    public FieldName context;
    public FieldName label;
    public FieldName tooltip;
    public String fieldapi;
    public String target;
}

private class Option
{
    public String label;
    public String value;
}

private class FieldName
{
    public String fieldName;
}
```

Comment: when you change and update picklist values, the updated value is not reflecting through event.detail.draftValues. Only standard field changes are getting from even.detail. So how we can save custom picklist field type records in lwc?